# Select items where local time is ~8AM

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called items. It contains a column tz with timezone identifiers (like America/New_York, Europe/London, etc).

I want to select all the items where the current time is 8AM +/- 5 minutes.

So if I run the query at 8AM EST it will return rows where tz = 'America/New_York'.
If I run the query at 9AM EST it will return rows where tz = 'America/Chicago'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE CAST(current_timestamp at time zone tz AS time) BETWEEN '07:55' AND '08:05'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be storing the [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) for each timezone. Then the query is as simple as

```
select * from items where GETDATE() between 
   DATEADD(minute,5,DATEADD(HOUR,offset,GETUTCDATE())) and   
   DATEADD(minute,-5,DATEADD(HOUR,offset,GETUTCDATE()))
```

I'm using SqlServer GETUTCDATE and DATEADD functions, but you can easily make them work in postgresql if you lookup the correct function names.

**EDIT**
If you can't add a offset to the table, create a timezone table with the string timezone and numeric offset. Join and run the above query.

Comment: But a simple numeric offset won't take into account daylight savings time.

Comment: Daylight savings time isn't practiced in all locales. Some US states and many countries don't use DST. http://www.infoplease.com/spot/daylight1.html

Comment: That doesn't invalidate the point that you should take it into account when it is in use.

Answer (score -1):

Your **tz** field is valid if it respects this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE

If so, I think this should work (no tested):

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE LOCALTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
(LOCALTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE tz) - interval '5 minutes' AND 
(LOCALTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE tz) + interval '5 minutes'
```

Comment: Some reference to 8 o'clock is missing.